# How to restrict the number of copies of a script can run a certain block of code?

Tags: semaphore, lockfile

I use `lockfile` to ensure a piece of code can only be run one at a time.

If I want to allow n copies of the same code run at a time, how to do it? Thanks.

```
if lockfile -1 lockfile.txt
then
  # something
  rm -f lockfile.txt
else
  echo error
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

gnu sem looks like a viable option: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html